# Ten suspicious coasters

Tags: visual, jigsaw-puzzle

Last Friday I've been out with nine friends and we went to a new bar in town, called *"Take it Easy"* bar or something. We had a great time as a group. Well, I think most of the group had. I wasn't paying too much attention, actually. To be honest, I easily get bored by the chit-chat of my friends.

Because of that, I might have been the only one paying attention to the coasters they were using at the bar. They had some abstract line patter on them, or so it seemed at first, but then I noticed that they came in different variants. After a bit of hunting, I could collect a set of ten different coasters. Look, I took a snapshot of them on the table:

[image: 10 coasters]

From then on, the evening improved substantially. Actually, I don't know when my friends left - way before me, for sure - but it was exactly 7 minutes after 3 a.m. that I finally decoded the hidden *"coaster message"* and could go home as a happier man than before.

> ### Can you find that message as well?
>
> (It is a quote. Do you know from whom?)

---

For convenience sake, here are 10 separate images of the coasters:

[C1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAZe0.png)
[C2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdrrf.png)
[C3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IjRT.png)
[C4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzp51.png)
[C5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPh7t.png)
[C6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2xFi.png)
[C7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8y9Xc.png)
[C8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgqzH.png)
[C9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMeQH.png)
[C10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAJ28.png)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's possible to get

> [image]

So...

> Googling "people make best things quote" gives
>  "Things turn out best for the people who make the best of the way things turn out."
>  by John Wooden
>  The numbers of i and w matches, and the mysterious E shape is the top part of T.

Update:

> The complete image:
>  [image]
>  Rotate the middle row counterclockwise and others clockwise to get the next one.

Comment: +1 The answer qute is correct and you will get the accepted answer check in ~1 day if no "better" answer comes along in the sense of an answer presenting the full jigsaw solution for the complete quote.

Comment: I'm working on this now.

Comment: Accepted as first and also complete. Well done.

Answer (score 8):

> Things turn out best for the people who make the best of the way things turn out.  -John Wooden
>  [image: things]
>  [image: Turn]
>  [image: Out]
>  [image: Best]
>  [image: For]
>  [image: the]
>  [image: people]
>  [image: who]
>  [image: make]
>  [image: the]
>  [image: Best]
>  [image: of]
>  [image: the]
>  [image: way]
>  [image: things]
>  [image: turn]
>  [image: Out]

Comment: Duplicated words can be constructed in multiple ways, so there are two "best", etc. I didn't find the 3rd "the", though.

Comment: Even better than I thought!  I noticed a partial duplicate but thought it was a red herring.  Go for it!  I got through it much faster with your first partial solution.

Comment: @user23013 I found it helpful to find partial words on each coaster and write those letters on the back of the card in a corresponding orientation.  Then when reconstructing the words, I'd reference my writing on the back to narrow down my options.  Seemed to be a fairly good system.  I even wrote partial/potential letters that could be formed by the edges of the coasters.

Comment: Most complete answer so far.(what are you using to do this and why are your images 3D tilted? I like it.) Just FYI: it is possible to get the whole phrase in 6 arrangements of the tiles. An answer showing that would get the check over your current one. (Right now, you'd be the winner of it.)

Comment: I printed your attachments, cut them out, went home, and spent time

Comment: I didn't use software, if that's what you're asking.  I used my brain and an iPhone to relay the pictures of my work.

Comment: I like that even more! As said, you can find an even more satisfying arrangement, but so far your answer is best.

Comment: Lol @BmyGuest, sign of the times. I assumed it was some sort of 3d tabletop simulator type software too. What is this "print" and "cut" Kujua speaks of?

Comment: @Alconja it is the way of the ancients, unbeknownst to the mere mortals of today's fickle world